# How to create count object array using date array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

My javascript array like that.

```
var datearray = [
    "2016-01-13", 
    "2016-01-18", 
    "2016-01-30", 
    "2016-02-13", 
    "2016-02-18", 
    "2016-02-28", 
    "2016-03-13", 
    "2016-03-23", 
    "2016-03-30", 
    "2016-04-13", 
    "2016-04-18", 
    "2016-04-30", 
    "2016-05-13", 
    "2016-05-18", 
    "2016-05-28", 
    "2016-06-13", 
    "2016-06-23", 
    "2016-06-30", 
    "2016-08-22"
]
```

but my searching dates are `startDate = 2015-12-01;` and `endDate = 2016-09-30;` I want to get new date array between above `startDate` and `endDate`. This new array will display like this,

```
var newOjArray = [
    {"2015-12":"0"},
    {"2016-01":"3"},
    {"2016-02":"3"},
    {"2016-03":"3"},
    {"2016-04":"3"},
    {"2016-05":"3"},
    {"2016-06":"3"},
    {"2016-07":"0"},
    {"2016-08":"1"},
    {"2016-09":"0"}
];
```

values meaning total count of considering date range. How I created It.

Comment: And what did you try so far ?   Have you at least tried to identify elements in the range of dates or something as basic as this ?

Comment: I want to get total count of month particular years.

Comment: I used this one to generate month array ,  var dateStart = moment("2015-12-01"); var dateEnd = moment("2016-09-30");  var timeValues = [];        while (dateEnd >= dateStart) {
                    timeValues.push(dateStart.format('YYYY-MM'));                    
                    dateStart.add(1, 'month');
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete proposal. With an array with the wanted grouped result.

```js
function getGroupedData(dates, from, to) {
    function pad(s, n) { return s.toString().length < n ? pad('0' + s, n) : s; }

    var temp = Object.create(null),
        result = [],
        fromYear = +from.slice(0, 4),
        fromMonth = +from.slice(5, 7),
        toYear = +to.slice(0, 4),
        toMonth = +to.slice(5, 7),
        o, k;

    datearray.forEach(function (d) {
        var k = d.slice(0, 7);
        temp[k] = (temp[k] || 0) + 1;
    });

    while (true) {
        k = pad(fromYear, 4) + '-' + pad(fromMonth, 2);
        o = {};
        o[k] = (temp[k] || 0).toString();
        result.push(o);
        if (fromYear === toYear && fromMonth === toMonth) {
            break;
        }
        fromMonth++;
        if (fromMonth > 12) {
            fromMonth = 1;
            fromYear++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var datearray = ["2016-01-13", "2016-01-18", "2016-01-30", "2016-02-13", "2016-02-18", "2016-02-28", "2016-03-13", "2016-03-23", "2016-03-30", "2016-04-13", "2016-04-18", "2016-04-30", "2016-05-13", "2016-05-18", "2016-05-28", "2016-06-13", "2016-06-23", "2016-06-30", "2016-08-22"];

console.log(getGroupedData(datearray, '2015-12-01', '2016-09-30'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter through this array. Taking advantage of your particular date format, we do not need to do any date arithmetic, we can simply compare dates as strings and use [`localeCompare()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp) to compare them:

```
var datearray = [
    "2016-01-13", 
    "2016-01-18", 
    "2016-01-30", 
    "2016-02-13", 
    "2016-02-18", 
    "2016-02-28", 
    "2016-03-13", 
    "2016-03-23", 
    "2016-03-30", 
    "2016-04-13", 
    "2016-04-18", 
    "2016-04-30", 
    "2016-05-13", 
    "2016-05-18", 
    "2016-05-28", 
    "2016-06-13", 
    "2016-06-23", 
    "2016-06-30", 
    "2016-08-22"
];

var startDate = "2015-12-01"; 
var endDate = "2016-01-30";

var filteredArray = datearray.filter(function(item){
  return item.localeCompare( startDate ) > -1 && endDate.localeCompare( item ) > -1;
});

console.log( filteredArray );
```

Now, you have the filteredArray and you can simply iterate through it to count the number of dates falling in a month.

Comment: each next month of range should be considered, that's why the OP included `{"2016-09":"0"}` into expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I think you mean I needed to format my filteredArray as specified by OP. But seems like this has solved OP's issue. Thanks.

Comment: look's like your answer was sufficient for the OP

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

Underscore.js has been used to manipulate data.

```js
var datearray=["2016-01-13","2016-01-18","2016-01-30","2016-02-13","2016-02-18","2016-02-28","2016-03-13","2016-03-23","2016-03-30","2016-04-13","2016-04-18","2016-04-30","2016-05-13","2016-05-18","2016-05-28","2016-06-13","2016-06-23","2016-06-30","2016-08-22"];

var boxingDay = new Date("12/01/2015");
var nextWeek  = new Date("09/30/2016");

function getDates( d1, d2 ){
  var oneDay = 24*3600*1000;
  for (var d=[],ms=d1*1,last=d2*1;ms<last;ms+=oneDay){
var new_Date=new Date(ms);
    d.push( new_Date.getFullYear()+"-"+("0" + (new_Date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) );
  }
  return d;
}

var x=[];
_.each(datearray, function(e){x.push(e.substring(0, 7));});

var z= _.uniq(getDates( boxingDay, nextWeek ));

var f=x.concat(_.uniq(getDates( boxingDay, nextWeek )));

document.getElementById("xx").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(_.countBy(f));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>

<div id="xx"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for a more `ES6` way then check it out:

```js
var dateArray = ["2016-01-13", "2016-01-18", "2016-01-30", "2016-02-13", "2016-02-18", "2016-02-28", "2016-03-13", "2016-03-23", "2016-03-30", "2016-04-13", "2016-04-18", "2016-04-30", "2016-05-13", "2016-05-18", "2016-05-28", "2016-06-13", "2016-06-23", "2016-06-30", "2016-08-22"];
var group = {};

dateArray.forEach(date =>
  group[(date = date.substr(0, 7))] =
  (group[date] || []).concat(date)
);
var result = Object.keys(group)
  .map(date => ({
    [date]: group[date].length
  }));

console.log(result)
```

If your date format is as the date array then the easiest way would be to use `substr` if the length is not constant then you can split it by spacer and then get the two first values. And if it's totally a date string you can create a date from this and convert it to your desired string as key of your object.